# Select multiple product options at once

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute, magento-community

I'm very new to Magento and I'm trying to build a website for a company which sells tooling and equipment to the aerospace industry.

A site similar to ours handles this very well:

http://www.panamericantool.com/cobalt-drills/drill-stops.html
http://www.panamericantool.com/cobalt-drills/drill-stops.html

They both have different attributes and quantities, and the customer can choose a few and have them all added to the cart at once.

How would I go about recreating something like this? I assume it will be some form of configurable product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a standard grouped product. The theme is customized to use `select` for quantity instead of `text` input, on top of other customizations. You should be able to approximate this in your base installation of Magento and then theme accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, I've added a follow up question here - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59241/handling-grouped-product-attributes - perhaps you could help with this too?